# MSVC DLL loading: are __declspec(dllexport) functions loaded directly without DllMain

Tags: delphi, dll, dllexport, dllmain

I tried to write a DLL project in VS C++ with some exported functions like below:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int function_sendNumber(unsigned num);
```

I noticed VS project comes with file dllmain.cpp containing DllMain entry function.
However, i commented the DllMain function and use Delphi exe application to
call the exported functions like below function pointer:

```
function  function_sendNumber(n : Integer): Integer; cdecl;
external 'DLLproject.dll';
```

The Delphi application successfully called the DLL exported function.
I thought this method is DLL Explicit linking.
So I want to understand clearly, is it Explicit Loading or implicit.
If so how exported functions are loaded without DllMain.
I don't find any calls to LoadLibrary to load DLL.

Comment: *DllMain* has nothing to do with implicit / explicit linking / loading. What is the question?

Comment: thanks @CristiFati. question is how the application found this export function without any DLL loading. i checked the dll by dump and only found export function name as entry point. is it like it directly look for export function name as entry point on dll file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of terms that are more or less connected:

- *Explicit / Implicit Linking* - this is kind of improper, because a *.dll* is either linked (by an *.exe* or another *.dll*) or not. A better term would be *Explicit / Implicit Loading*, because of the way a *.dll* is loaded:

  1. *Explicit*ly - on demand (using *LoadLibrary*, *LoadLibraryEx*, or other (lower level) mechanism) from its client code
  2. *Implicit*ly - by default (automatically, by *Win* at process startup ***<sup>(check next bullet)</sup>***). These *.dll*s are linked by the *.exe* (or another *.dll* linked (recursively) by the *.exe*)
  3. [[MS.Docs]: Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) - meet the above 2 options in the middle, taking the advantages from each (meaning that the *.dll* will still be loaded automatically (so it's still *Implicit Loading*), but only at the point when it's needed (one of its functions called), instead of process startup)
- [[MS.Docs]: DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) the function that it's being executed when a *.dll* is loaded into a process, **regardless** of the load method (above)
- *function_sendNumber* - is exported by your *.dll* because of ***__declspec(dllexport)*** (and the name is kept simple (even if code is compiled as *C++*) because of *extern "C"*)
- The fact that you can call the function from *Delphi* is because:

  - It's exported by the *.dll*
  - ***external*** keyword ([[Embarcadero.DocWiki]: Procedures and Functions (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)))
  - **The function is actually called** from *Delphi* code

  With these 3 items checked, *Delphi* did the (under the hood) work of linking the *.dll* by the *.exe*, and as a consequence you have **Implicit Loading** (worth mentioning @HeartWare's suggestion to also mark a function as ***delayed*** from *Delphi*, in order to benefit from *Delayed Loading*)

Comment: You can make the import a Delay-Loaded one by adding the directive _delayed;_ to your Delphi declaration. This will mean that the .DLL file will only be loaded at the first call to it, and not (as in Implicit Load) at main program startup.

Comment: @HeartWare: Good point! That's an optimization that can happen after current aspects are clear.